# ActiveAdmin on Win 8 Pro 64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, activeadmin

I recently installed ActiveAdmin on Windows 8 Pro 64, when I issue the 'rails server' command and go to view ActiveAdmin in Google Chrome I am displayed with the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new

Showing C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #12 raised:

(in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-  0.5.1/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/namespace.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag style.path, style.options %>
10:   <% end %>
11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
13:   <% end %>
14: 
15:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

I have tried the solution given here and still no luck:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1773

I have never had a problem installing and running ActiveAdmin on Win 7 and Mac OS X. I am curious if any other user has came across this problem and know of a solution?

I really don't want to downgrade to Win 7 again :(

I have ensured Java is installed and working correctly also.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the active_admin.js within my app folder, from this location:

```
app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
```

Thought I would add this in case another user gets stuck here :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you haven't actually resolved the issue, you've only removed the activeadmin javascript. While this will stop the error message appearing, it also kills any activeadmin javascript functionality, which is far from ideal.

From my own experience, resolving the ExecJS::RuntimeError is an environment issue when using coffeescript, not an activeadmin issue - some suggest adding `gem 'therubyracer'` to your Gemfile, but I've had issues getting that to build successfully.

For me, the above issue was resolved by installing node.js.